# Lucene web paging

Tags: lucene

I am creating a web app with `Lucene` that I need to implement paging.  I have seen here the different examples about using an offset on the collector.  However, those seem to be old.  `Lucene 3.5` (or 3.6 can't remember which) added this I believe.  I have seen the `IndexSearcher` method `searchAfter`.  However, it requires you pass it the last `ScoreDoc`.  Because this is a web app, I have no way to pass the last result (as a ScoreDoc object) to the next request.  So, my question is how is this typically done?

The only way that I have really come up with is to add in a unique key into the index when building.  Then, pass that key as a post parameter when trying to get the next page.  Then, I would have to search for that key to get the document id and pull that document to use with searchAfter.  I think I have to use my own unique key because I cannot rely on the document id to stay the same.  Am I correct on this?

If there are better ways, please let me know.  This is my first attempt at Lucene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, it requires you pass it the last ScoreDoc. Because this is a web app, I have no way to pass the last result (as a ScoreDoc object) to the next request. So, my question is how is this typically done?

I don't understand your problem, if you want to use searchAfter, just make a ScoreDoc to pass to it. your webapp can pass ints and floats right?

```
  /** Constructs a ScoreDoc. */
  public ScoreDoc(int doc, float score) {
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough.  The existing code is all in PHP.  I am writing a java program for PHP to call to do the search.  From one HTTP request to the next, I can't (or not sure how) pass the info I need in the POST parms.  What int would I pass?  It is my understanding that I can't rely on the docID.  So, do I create my own unique key in the index and pass that to the page 2 HTTP request.  Then do a search for that key, pull the doc, make a ScoreDoc, and pass that to searchAfter.  Just looking for the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, what you are doing at the moment is correct. A ScoreDoc which you construct yourself using ints and floats will not work. See my similar question:

[Working Lucene SearchAfter Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057613/working-lucene-searchafter-example)