# Working Lucene SearchAfter Example

Tags: java, lucene

I'm trying to use Lucene 4.8.1's SearchAfter methods to implement paging of search results in a web application.

A similar question has been asked before, but the accepted answer given there does not work for me:

[Stack Overflow Question: Lucene web paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485040/lucene-web-paging)

When I create a Lucene ScoreDoc from scratch in this way to use as an argument for SearchAfter:

```
   ScoreDoc sd = new ScoreDoc(14526, 0.0f);
   TopDocs td = indexSearcher.searchAfter(sd, query, null, PAGEHITS);
```

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: after must be a FieldDoc
```

This appears contrary to the documentation. But in any case, when I create a Field Doc instead, I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: after.fields wasn't set
```

after.fields is an Object array, so I can hardly set that with information I can pass in a URI!

I cannot find any working code examples using SearchAfter. My original plan was obviously to create a new ScoreDoc as the previous question suggests. Can anybody suggest what I might be doing wrong, or link to any working code examples of SearchAfter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can create a scoredoc and then pass it to searchAfter. You need to use the ScoreDocs returned from a previous search.

Comment: Thanks. After experimenting extensively with this, I think that you are right. However, the API does not explicitly state this: http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#searchAfter(org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc, org.apache.lucene.search.Query, int) It probably should. Also, I would like to know how the Lucene developers expect deep paging to be efficiently achieved in a web application. Some working example code for SearchAfter would also be nice. I will keep investigating this.

Comment: I suggest keeping an LRU cache of page boundary scoredocs and their respective positions. New positions are added to the cache as new pages are discovered. To cut down on searches, when scrolling backwards and forwards, the search begins from nearest cached position.

Answer (score 0):

can you have a try.

```
@Test
public void searchAfter() {
    Object[] objects = new Object[]{"1"};
    List<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    boolean type = true;
    while (type) {
        SearchHits searchHits = searchAfter(objects);
        SearchHit[] hits = searchHits.getHits();
        if (hits != null && hits.length > 0){
            objects = hits[hits.length-1].getSortValues();
            if (hits.length < size) type = false;
            for (SearchHit hit : hits) {
                data.add(hit.getSourceAsMap());
                System.out.println(JsonUtil.objectToJson(hit.getSourceAsMap()));
            }
        }

    }
    Iterator<Map<String, Object>> iterator = data.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next().toString());
    }
    System.out.println(data.size() + "-----------------");

}

public SearchHits searchAfter(Object[] objects) {
    SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.termQuery("age", "33"));
    sourceBuilder.size(size);
    sourceBuilder.sort("account_number", SortOrder.ASC);
    sourceBuilder.searchAfter(objects);

    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
    searchRequest.indices("bank");
    searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
    ActionFuture<SearchResponse> response = elasticsearchTemplate.getClient().search(searchRequest);

    SearchHits searchHits = response.actionGet().getHits();
    return searchHits;
}
```